# Host main domain on Apache and some of the sub-domains on Nginx

Tags: apache, nginx, subdomain, gitlab, linode

I recently bought a linode 1GB plan. Installed Apache on it, had my website up and running on it.
However I installed [gitlab](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq) on the server and mapped it to a sub-domain. Since the installation guides recommended using Nginx as the server, I installed it and is running on port 80. Currently my apache is not running since there are port conflicts.
But I fixed it by editing the `/etc/apache2/ports.conf` file and instructing apache to serve on a different port.
Now when I visit the main domain that is pointing to a port(8000) and using apache doesn't show up.
gitlab is installed at `http://gitlab.myserver.com` and I am able to access it., but if I try to navigate to `http://myserver.com`, I get the content of `http://gitlab.myserver.com`

My gitlab config serving under Nginx is as follows:

```
# GITLAB
# Maintainer: @randx
# App Version: 5.0

upstream gitlab {
 server unix:/home/git/gitlab/tmp/sockets/gitlab.socket;
}

server {
  listen my_server_ip default_server;  # e.g., listen 192.168.1.1:80; In most    cases *:80 is a good idea
  server_name gitlab.myserver.com;         # e.g., server_name source.example.com;
  server_tokens off;     # don't show the version number, a security best practice
  root /home/git/gitlab/public;

# individual nginx logs for this gitlab vhost
access_log  /var/log/nginx/gitlab_access.log;
error_log   /var/log/nginx/gitlab_error.log;

location / {
  # serve static files from defined root folder;.
  # @gitlab is a named location for the upstream fallback, see below
  try_files $uri $uri/index.html $uri.html @gitlab;
}

# if a file, which is not found in the root folder is requested,
# then the proxy pass the request to the upsteam (gitlab unicorn)
location @gitlab {
  proxy_read_timeout 300; # https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/694
  proxy_connect_timeout 800; # https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/694
  proxy_redirect     off;

  proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
  proxy_set_header   Host              $http_host;
  proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP         $remote_addr;

  proxy_pass http://gitlab;
 }
}
```

My Apache config for `myserver.com` is as follows:

```
# domain: myserver.com
# public: /home/me/public/myserver.com/

<VirtualHost *:8000>
 # Admin email, Server Name (domain name), and any aliases
 ServerAdmin webmaster@myserver.com
 ServerName  www.myserver.com
 ServerAlias myserver.com

 # Index file and Document Root (where the public files are located)
 DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
 DocumentRoot /home/me/public/myserver.com/public

 # Log file locations
 LogLevel warn
 ErrorLog  /home/me/public/myserver.com/log/error.log
 CustomLog /home/me/public/myserver.com/log/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue. The issue was with the following line in my gitlab config:

```
server {
  listen my_ip default_server;
  server_name gitlab.myserver.com;         # e.g., server_name source.example.com;
  server_tokens off;     # don't show the version number, a security best practice
  root /home/git/gitlab/public;
  ......
}
```

I changed this to the following:

```
server {
      listen 80;
      server_name gitlab.myserver.com;         # e.g., server_name source.example.com;
      server_tokens off;     # don't show the version number, a security best practice
      root /home/git/gitlab/public;
      ......
    }
```

And I followed your instructions on serving sites on apache via nginx by using proxy_pass

Thanks a lot..
Cheers....

Comment: Hi, do you have any idea how to solve this problem on Apache?

Answer (score 1):

A good solution is to continue to run Nginx on port 80, while adding proxy directives to Nginx to serve as a proxy for specific domains that are running on Apache. An example Nginx configuration:

```
server {
    server_name  www.myserver.com;
    server_name myserver.com;

   location / {
      proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
   }
}
```

I do this myself, and it works great.

Comment: I have a file called /etc/nginx/sites-available/gitlab
So do you mean to say that I Need to create a file /etc/nginx/sites-available/myserver.com and include the above code there?

Comment: Doesn't work. Whenever I navigate to myserver.com, it displays the content of gitlab. For instance, the default page of gitlab is the sign in page. So when I hit http://myserver.com, it takes me to http://myserver.com/users/sign_in

Comment: And after the change, you reloaded or restarted the nginx service? You can also try adding "listen 80;" to the server block, although usually this is the default.

Comment: Yeah I had restarted Nginx after the changes.
But I get the following error now when I restart apache:
apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.0.1 for ServerName
[Fri Aug 02 11:25:50 2013] [warn] _default_ VirtualHost overlap on port 80, the first has precedence

Comment: I don't think the answer involved any updates your Apache configurations. You should post your updated Apache configs if you'd like help with it.

Comment: `
  <VirtualHost *:8000>
   # Admin email, Server Name (domain name), and any aliases
   ServerAdmin webmaster@myserver.com
   ServerName  www.myserver.com
   ServerAlias myserver.com 

   # Index file and Document Root (where the public files are located)
   DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
   DocumentRoot /home/me/public/myserver.com/public

   # Log file locations
   LogLevel warn
   ErrorLog  /home/me/public/myserver.com/log/error.log
   CustomLog /home/me/public/myserver.com/log/access.log combined
  </VirtualHost>`